# How to use select_related in save method of a admin model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-select-related

I would like to get the specific information from different model therefore I have use the method of select_related to fetch the data but I unable to save the record into db.
How to use select_related in save method?

Let say I have following models
[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJmPz.png)

Now I would like to get the product_quantity from stocklist and do a subtraction between product_quantity and shipping_qty(from stockOut models) to get the final quantity that remain.

[admin.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIQXC.jpg)

But I unable to save/update the value into db when I use the method of select_related to get the specific information. How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Please paste your code into the question. It is easier for the community to view.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you don't get only `shipping_qty` if you do `stockOut.objects.all().select_related("shipping_qty")` but you get all stockOut instances with their shipping_qty and stocks

what you want is, to get these values for only the current instance

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    stock = obj.stock
    shipping_qty = obj.shipping_qty
    if shipping_qty and stock.quantity_in_store:
        obj.shipping_qty = stokc.quantity_in_store - shipping_qty
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```